# AngularJS ajax http promise returns additional data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

In the promise then function when you receive the data object it is wrapped with another data object like

```
data = Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

How to avoid this. you need to access your variables like data.data.myVar

```
var test123 = $scope.test();
    test123.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        // why you need to access your data in "data.data.myValue"   
    },function(data){

    });


$scope.test = function(){
        var promise =  $http(
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: 'json/requestKey.json'
                }
        )
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            //return data;
        });
        return promise;
};
```

Comment: It allows you to also access `data.status` or `data.statusText` apparently… What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the data part from your "service". And you can ditch the redundant  promise since `$http` is already a promise.

```
$scope.test().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

$scope.test = function() {
  return $http('json/requestKey.json').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is be resolved two ways

1. Try returning the resulting object instead of wrapping it around another object and then returning that to the client on the server side.
2. In the `success()` callback of your `$http`, return `data.data` instead of just `return data`, so that in your `then()` function you will get the internal object.

Comment: You cannot return from a `.success` callback.

Comment: @Bergi: Isn't it same as `jQuery.ajax` ?

Comment: No, `$http` (angular) is different from `$.ajax` (jQuery). And even in jQuery you cannot return from `success` callbacks, you have to use `then` (or `pipe` in old versions).

Comment: The `succes()`callback should not be used anymore as it is deprecated since Angular 1.4.

Comment: @cverb:yeah i realised that

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning, HttpResponseMessage, REST api response data in this format,

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

To parse in ajax success call back,

```
  $http.get(urlBase + '/get/' + id).then(function (response) {
                  var yourData = response['data'];
                  var yourStatusCode = response['status'];
                  var yourStatusText = response['statusText'];

                  //assign data to any other $scope object 
                  $scope.product = yourData;
              }, function (error) {
                            console.log('error occured!!');
              });
```

You will do fine now, you don't need to change the response from web api now.